# trouble installing pygame on python 3.5

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.5, python-wheel

I have installed the whl file for pygame 1.9.2 for python 3.5 32 bit and have put it in "C:\Python35\Scripts". When i open a command window in the scripts folder and type

```
pip3 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl
```

it says

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

I am following the instructions from [here](https://skellykiernan.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/python-pygame-install/), I have heard it works for python 3.5. I have been trying to figure this out for ages, can anyone help me on what to do next?

Comment: can you include full log from installation?

Answer (score 8):

Here are instructions for users with the newer **Python 3.5**:

I just successfully installed Pygame 1.9.2a0-cp35 on Windows and it runs with Python 3.5.1.

- Install Python, and remember the install location
- Go [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and download `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl`
- Move the downloaded .whl file to your `python35/Scripts` directory
- Open a command prompt in the `Scripts` directory (`Shift`-`Right click` in the directory > `Open a command window here`)
- Enter the command:

  `pip3 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl`
- If you get an error in the last step, try:

  `python -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl`

And that should do it. Tested as working on Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: For future users, I was getting an error trying this method saying "XXXX.whl is not a support wheel on this platform." The fix for me was just going to the \Scripts directory in the command prompt and then simply running "pip install pygame." It only worked in the \Scripts directory, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run

```
python -m pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win32.whl
```

This should be a workaround the ["space problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24627525) of pip on windows.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: when i run it it says python is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @0swald: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621277/4594443) answer for details about "How do I run a python program in the Command Prompt".