# Pytest-bdd unable to launch

Tags: python, python-3.x, bdd, pytest

I am using python 3.5 (32 bit).
I have installed pytest-bdd on my laptop.
But for some reason the pytest-bdd command is not being recognized.
The warning I get is Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

I have attached a screenshot of the error.
Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a pytest-bdd error, instead it's a pip error (a gift with python 3.5).
See here to fix the problem:
[Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)