# Installing Django using pip

Tags: django, pip

I'm trying to install Django using pip on my windows machine, however i keep getting an error in command prompt:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

I've been searching around on the internet for solutions, but I cant seem to find any. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What command(s) do you run and what software do you use?

Comment: Did you set environment variables properly?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall yes, ive set the paths in the environment variables

Comment: @Leistungsabfall Just a note, when i installed python, it gave me the option to set the PATH, im assuming that is that is the same thing?

Comment: @Prash yes, as long as you did not change it. What pip version do you have? Maybe try upgrading pip: `python -m pip install -U pip`

Comment: @Leistungsabfall says that it is all up to date

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a virtual env setup. Then activate it and try installing django.

Answer (score 0):

Try use the python installation from Active State http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads

I'm a Linux User but I've used python and Django on Windows with ActiveState.

When you install it, the installation create a folder with any utils tools, like pip, easy_install and etc... And the pip of this script works well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
python -m pip install django
```

as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)