# Python 3.4.4 - pip collection error

Tags: python, pip

I would really appreciate some help on the below query - I've been trying to get pip to work for the best of a day and really struggling.

Regardless of which module I try to install I keep getting a "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openpyxl (from version s: ) 
No matching distribution found for openpyxl

Please see a screenshot below of the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsaOx.png)

I've looked at around the website, including the following posts, to help with installing pip but still unsure as to why it isn't working.

['pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

[Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Do you runnung cmd as Administrator? Because it looks like you python installed globally (in Program files), thus you need to run pip as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the internet connection?
From your screenshot, seems like you cannot access the URL as follow:.
https://pypi.python.org/simple/openpyxl/

Comment: Hi yes, my internet connection seems to be working fine - but it definitely seems to be a connection problem of some kind

Comment: Have you tried to open the link from browser? Is it accessible?

Comment: Can I know which version of python you installed?

Comment: I just found a link for installing openpyxl with winpython, would you try if it helps? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/winpython/wjs4RWLXbKw

Comment: Believe it or not that hasn't worked either!

I'm getting an Error "Unable to install openpyxl-2.4.0 b1

I'll try it with another package.

Comment: If possible, I think it's better to use official python package as there are much more resource on the internet.

Comment: @Gilli243 Hope you are trying it from elevated command prompt