# Python-docx installation error. Cannot import 'etree'

Tags: pip, python-3.5, python-docx, pyperclip

I am using using Pycharms to program using Python3.5.  I tried to import docx module and I am getting the error shown in the picture.  I am not able to do any pip install either.  I get a fatal error shown in the second picture.

[image: import docx]
[image: pip install]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)