# How to start Jupyter notebook in windows?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have had some Python installations on a windows machine. I installed Jupyter but wasn't able to run it.
So, I manually uninstall all libraries I could found. And then, installed the complete conda package.

Now when I give the jupyter run command, I get the following o/p:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Python27\python.exe"  "C:\Python27\Scripts\jupyter.exe" not
ebook'
```

Comment: you used `jupyter notebook` command to run jupyter. right?

Comment: I guess this is similar [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86]

Comment: Yes I used Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: @Take_Care_ : Nope, its not same. I am looking for a conda solution.

Comment: Most likely you need to edit your PATH environment variable and remove the Python27 directories