# conda environment doesn't launch jupyter or recognize pip

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I created a conda environment (with python 3.6 and Anaconda 3-5.2.0 on a Windows 10 machine) and activated it. I then installed both jupyter and pip using `conda install jupyter` and `conda install pip`. Both commands executed without problems.

When I type `jupyter notebook` or `pip install [some package]` I get this:

[image]

The same happens for the pip command. What might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: try adding " to the path of the first line in `-*-script.py`,  for example `#!C:/Path/to/python.exe`will be `#!"C:/Path/to/python.exe"`

Comment: maybe duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480173/fatal-error-when-starting-jupyter-notebook