# C:\Windows\system32>pip install pandasFatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I have recently installed python-2.7.14 (32-bit) on windows 10. But when I try to install any package using command pip install XXX, it gives me above error.

I tried all solution to this existing problem but it didn't work for me.
My python is installed on C:\Python27

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: As my path didn't have any spaces there was no need to remove quotes from the path in pip.exe mentioned in the above commented duplicate link.
python -m pip install XXX  works for me but don't know why 
just pip install XXX is not working. But when I try to open jupyter notebook from cmd it gives me same error Fatal error in the launcher: Unable to create process using '"'. Hence I thought it might be some problem in my pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python -m pip install XXX
```

worked for me but when I tried to open jupyter notebook in windows command prompt by typing

```
jupyter notebook
```

It used to give me the same **Fatal** error.

Actually, it was my antivirus **mcafee** at organisational level which was blocking the exe to run.

To solve this I had installed python in **D:\** folder.