# pip installation error on windows 7 (32-bit)

Tags: python, windows-7, pip

i installed the pip on windows 7(32-bit) but i have below error.

```
    C:\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip --version
    Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

    C:\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>pip install httpie
    Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

i have saved get-pip.py file in C:\Python.
i have set the system variables also.i have followed the page for installation https://dev.to/el_joft/installing-pip-on-windows
can someone help here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)

Comment: install official python distribution of windows. it have pip inbuilt or use winpython distribution.

Comment: use winpython https://winpython.github.io/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below command solved my problem

```
         python -m pip install pip==9.0.1
```

found in [Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using/37228413)