# pip Installed biopython, but it won't compile Bio Module

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, biopython

I have biopython installed, but it keeps saying no module named Biopython

I had this working previously so I know it works, but I wanted the program to compile on a different computer. I installed python on the computer (version 3.7.3) and installed Pycharm Community Edition as the IDE. After that I installed pip and did the following in the pycharm terminal:

`pip install biopython`

Output:

```
Requirement already satisfied: biopython in c:\users\thisi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.73)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\thisi\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from biopython) (1.16.4)
```

Yet, whenever I compile the program, I get the following error.

```
C:\Users\thisi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/thisi/Desktop/H-protein/py-scripts/protein-blastp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/thisi/Desktop/H-protein/py-scripts/protein-blastp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have browsed the internet for hours to find a solution, but none seem to work as they are tailored to linux.

Other Relevant Details:
My OS is Windows10

If I open the project interpreter, it shows biopython package installed in my current project and python 3.7 as the interpreter. Any help would be appreciated.

`from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastpCommandline`

I just need the first line of code to compile
The function I gave is an example of how I use the biopython package

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple version of python installed?

Comment: I know this response is rather late but yeah, you were right. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [biopython no module named Bio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848517/biopython-no-module-named-bio)