# biopython ModuleNotFoundError when running script in anaconda env

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, biopython

Please have mercy on me. I'm from the R universe and recently inherited a project in python. It's been about two years since I've had to work with python, so I'm probably missing something obvious. And I'll do my best for a reprex if anyone should deem it necessary.

I have an anaconda environment running on ubuntu 20.04. I've activated the environment and then installed biopython. However, whenever I run the script file in question, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Here's the full error:

`from Bio import SeqIO ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'`

After doing some digging, turns out `Bio` is actually within `biopython`, and when I run `conda list | grep 'Bio'` I get nothing as output. However, when I run `conda list | grep 'bio'` here's the output.

`# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/bioPy: biopython                 1.78             py38h7b6447c_0`

Here's the output from `which python3`

`/home/user/anaconda3/envs/bioPy/bin/python3`

I also fired up the interpreter directly, from within the active environment then ran `import Bio` then used the methods I wanted to use, and had no issues. But if I tried to import `biopython` I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. So I'm pretty sure that `Bio` is what I actually need for the script to run

I read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848517/biopython-no-module-named-bio) about manually changing the name of the package directory in the site-packages directory located at `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.x/site-packages`. Seemed far-fetch, but didn't make a difference because the directory was already named 'Bio' in site-packages.

I see from the [biopython website](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.html) that `Bio` is the API for the biopython project, and that the particular piece of code I want is a separate package within the API (SeqIO).

So here's my question. How is one supposed to get methods from within the `Bio` package imported into a python script?

Comment: Probably an issue with pathing due to how you are calling the anaconda environment. Some useful resources:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html
https://www.biostars.org/p/396486/

Comment: Import 'sys' module and run: `print(sys.version)` and `print(sys.path)`

Comment: Please provide the printed output when you run this via interpreter and bash (conda env).

Comment: `print(sys.version)` yields: `3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 07:30:14) 
[GCC 7.3.0]` and `print(sys.path)` yields: `['', '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/bioPy/lib/python38.zip', '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/bioPy/lib/python3.8', '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/bioPy/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/bioPy/lib/python3.8/site-packages']`

Comment: You are able to use 'Bio' via interpreter but not via bash (assuming this is how you encountered `ModuleNotFoundError`. Please provide the output for both interpreter (method you can load 'Bio') AND bash (method you cannot load 'Bio'). I'm guessing you'll get different results, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: If you do get different results, you'll want to look at how you're calling the conda python environment (review documentation).

Comment: Thank you @Ghoti for the response. I won’t be able to access that machine again until tomorrow at the earliest. One question though, when you say “calling” the conda environment do you mean calling `conda activate` or `conda create`?

Comment: I mean whatever method you've been trying to use unsuccessfully (bash). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Interpreter output: `<Bio.SeqIO.QualityIO.FastqPhredIterator object at 0x7f956eca1640>
`  Bash output: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Scripts/run_fastq_analyzer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Bio import SeqIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio'`