# Module not found error in conda environment

Tags: python, import, anaconda, conda, environment

I'm having issues using a package in my conda environment. The package is clearly in my environment, but when I run a script using an interpreter from the environment, I get ModuleNotFoundError. I've tried everything for the past few hours but can't figure it out. Does anyone know what the issue is? Thanks

```
(pythonProject) C:\Users\...\Desktop\Other\CS\Rosalind\Bioinformatics Stronghold>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\tools\Anaconda3\envs\pythonProject:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
biopython                 1.78             py38he774522_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2021.1.19            haa95532_1
certifi                   2020.12.5        py38haa95532_0
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254
mkl                       2020.2                      256
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38h196d8e1_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py38h46781fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h47e9c7a_0
numpy                     1.19.2           py38hadc3359_0
numpy-base                1.19.2           py38ha3acd2a_0
openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0
pip                       21.0.1           py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_4
setuptools                52.0.0           py38haa95532_0
six                       1.15.0           py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.35.2               h2bbff1b_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0

(pythonProject) C:\Users\...\Desktop\Other\CS\Rosalind\Bioinformatics Stronghold>python FIBD.py 1 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FIBD.py", line 3, in <module>
    import biopython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'biopython'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [biopython no module named Bio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848517/biopython-no-module-named-bio)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the official documentation, you have to `import Bio` instead of `import biopython`. If you still have issues, refer to the documentation provided

Documentation:

https://biopython.org/wiki/Getting_Started