# biopython, Import error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Bio''

Tags: python, importerror, biopython

I tried importing the file 'Bio' from the Biopython module to use the seqIO file.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
with open("uniprot.fa", "rt") as handle:
    for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta"):
        print(record.id)
```

[image: the output showed an error:]

Then I changed the path as advised

[image: and the output showed another error]

I'm confused plz help.

PS:I tried uninstalling and installing it again through pip and through zip file and I'm still facing this issue.

Comment: How did you install BioPython? e.g. via pip or Conda?

Comment: I installed it using ' -pip install biopython '

Comment: Do you have multiple version of pip and/or Python? You can check with `which pip` and `which python`. They should be located in the same directory, otherwise modules you install with pip won't be found by Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [biopython no module named Bio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848517/biopython-no-module-named-bio)