# PIP fatal error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I get a fatal error when using pip install.

```
pip install praw
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '""c:\program files\python36\python.exe"  
"C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe" install praw'
```

But when i do the samething but with Python in beginning, it works they way as it used to when using just pip install.

```
python -m pip install praw
```

I have no idea whats causing this issue and I'm not sure how to fix this.
[Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86) gives a workaround and not a fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)

Comment: Its answer provides only a workaround and not an actual fix.

Comment: The point abut a duplicate question is that it has been asked before, it does not mean there is a fix, often there is no fix.

Comment: I just want to understand why this issue is happening. It was working fine before and now its not. Wherever i searched, it had this workaround only. Not sure what changed.

Comment: pip 10.0.0 just came out, I expect that's what changed for you.  When I updated, I get the same error now.  The python -m workaround still works, but this isn't the first time this specific bug has been introduced.  I expect to have to wait until a new pip release for it to be resolved.

Comment: @BlivetWidget Can confirm, just updated and now have this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible your problem is caused by this issue introduced in pip 10.0.0: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5223

Your options are limited to waiting for a maintenance release (which shouldn't be too far off since the underlying bug https://bitbucket.org/pypa/distlib/issues/104/generated-wrapper-scripts-fail-when-python has already been fixed) or downgrading to pip 9.

Comment: I checked and I do have pip 10.0.0.
I have a script that is automatically updating all python modules in the background on a schedule. Probably this was upgraded at that time..