# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using

Tags: python

When I type anything to the console when I use Django, I get the following error:

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using'""c:\program           files\python36\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\django-admin.exe" startproject testsite`

Comment: You'll have to include your code to get any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading Django.

```
pip install django --upgrade
```