# How to completely erase Python 3 from Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had Python 3 working well on Windows 10, with Anaconda installed. When I uninstalled Anaconda, something went wrong and I started having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86).

I tried all the solutions but nothing worked. I decided to reinstall Python. I uninstalled with no issues (the `scripts` and `lib/site-packages` directories were not deleted, but I assume that's the correct behavior) and when I install again, all the executables and files in the main directory, including python.exe, are not installed. I also tried the web installer but got the same results.

If Python cannot be reinstalled, that means that when I uninstalled it something remained in Windows. How to get rid of Python completely?

Comment: After uninstall Open `cmd` and run `whereis python` `whereis pip` delete those files. for anaconda uninstall from control panel , also see if any files left over in **C:\Users\Username\Anaconda3** *(usually)*

Comment: did you mean `where` instead of `whereis` ? Didn't find anything.

Comment: `whereis` it is. If you want to completely erase why not delete scripts and lib-site packages folders

Comment: sorry, cannot find whereis. I searched in explorer and couldn't find neither python nor pip. I did delete the scripts and lib folders, still Python doesn't create the folder again in the installation

Comment: Did you run the command in command prompt ? Delete those scripts and lib/site-packages and do fresh install of latest python. Seems your scripts folder is corrupt

Comment: no, I run the exe from windows explorer

Comment: Fixed the problem, the default installs at user level in AppData folder, I checked "install for all users" and it installed in c:\Program Files