# Fatal error when running anything with Pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I've had some issues installing pip packages, so I decided to uninstall python, and reinstall it.  However, when I downloaded it again, and tried to run pip, I got this error

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe"
```

Comment: just to make sure you installed it correctly try in terminal "pip --version" & "python --version". see if no error

Comment: @Vanz "pip --version" throws the same error (any pip command does)

Comment: Can you launch python by itself, or do you still get an error?

Comment: try adding pip in your'e system path variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade pip:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

This is more of a workaround than a proper fix. See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24627797) for more information.