# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using pip.exe

Tags: python, command-prompt

Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pygame'

I have been trying to use pip installations in command prompt for the past while now and keep getting this issue. the first file location now no longer exists. Can anyone help me with this problem please ?

Comment: i think you need to update pip location in your `PATH`

Comment: Try `python -m pip install pygame`.

Comment: John i tried doing that, and nothing happened in command prompt but i didnt get any error this time

Comment: Is this the full error you are getting? If there i more please post it. maybe pip is trying to put stuff at system path and your system is like NO. Maybe try to move install location to some userland like documents or desktop. Maybe pipenv can also help here.

Comment: yes this is the full error. I have just installed the newest version of python directly onto my C drive. My system path is up to date but i cannot find any reference to the first path (c:\users\owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe) mentioned in the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "file path1" file path2" : The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419086/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-file-path1-file-path2)

Answer (score 1):

When we are looking at the execution file of pip, we can see the major entry file of python that pip is using, modify it to right path, and its done!
Or as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55210770/7621301 , you can reinstall pip.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall your current python and its launcher from control penal
   Then download new python version and install it
2. While installing new one make sure you tick Add Launcher to all users(recommended) and ADD python to PATH both.
3. Now click customized install and tick all the boxes and install it
4. After install complete open powershell or cmd and type python to check it is
   installed properly if you see:
   PS C:\Users\Rohit> python
   Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > exit()

type exit() for quit python
This that means successfully installed

4.Now let's type pip + ENTER
if you see multiple pip commands congratulations your good to go

5.Okay then try to install your required python library
e.g : pip install pyttsx

PS C:\Users\Rohit> pip install pyttsx3
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyttsx3
Using cached pyttsx3-2.90-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting pywin32
Using cached pywin32-302-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
Collecting pypiwin32
Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
Collecting comtypes
Using cached comtypes-1.1.10.tar.gz (145 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for comtypes, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pywin32, pypiwin32, comtypes, pyttsx3

If your see this kind of stuff, your problem is solved.

NOTE : In case it not solved go to Microsoft store and install python and launch it. Then press windows button and search for edit environment variable >> environment variable. Check if python is added to the PATH if not then add it.