# Cant install selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

Im trying to selenium in python 3.8.0 but it doesn't work I get this error: Fatal error in launcher:

> Unable to create process using '"c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install selenium'

Comment: Can you provide some more details? What did you run to get this error?

Comment: `python3.8.0 != Python37-32`

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

Comment: possibly duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182083/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-pip-exe

Answer (score 0):

> Try including your pip into your environmental variables and also your Scripts directory