# Fatal error in launcher: when using flask run

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, python-venv

I have instantly got into this error without changing any file or configuration related to the file but when I got into my API folder in order to run my backend server

```
F:\projects\scl\api>venv                                      //initiated the virtual environment
(venv) F:\projects\scl\api>run                               //after running this particular code
(venv) F:\projects\scl\api>flask run --host=0.0.0.0
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using'"f:\projects\school\api\venv\scripts\python.exe"  "F:\projects\scl\api\venv\Scripts\flask.exe" run --host=0.0.0.0': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"f:\projects\school\api\venv\scripts\python.exe"
> "F:\projects\scl\api\venv\Scripts\flask.exe" run --host=0.0.0.0': The
> system cannot find the file specified.

this error prompts out after running this code where the path **"f:\projects\school\api\venv\scripts\python.exe"** this path is not present in the same drive emphasizing the **f:** and the **school** folder in this particular *PATH*.

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling **pip** and gone through other articles but seems not the common one which I am facing but hence see no change but still struggling how to clear out this error.

[Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using "file path1" file path2" : The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419086/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-file-path1-file-path2)

Comment: As the link says, does `python -m flask run` work?

Comment: Otherwise, where did you create your venv? Are you moving it around between different folders? Otherwise, where did `"f:\projects\school` come from?

Comment: **python -m flask run** does not work because through that I am unable to fetch the data . And the venv I have created in the **"F:\projects\scl\api\ "** and I haven't moved any of these filesstill it is coming without my notice.

Answer (score 0):

Export the file to be run before

```sh
$ export FLASK_APP=hello
$ flask run
```

See the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/) for a complete overview as well as [this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-run-flask-application) article.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced this problem aswell, just deleted my **venv** folder and then created a new one using

`$ python3 -m venv venv`

Here the second `venv` would be your new venv folder name. You'll have to reinstall all the modules you had installed but it's a quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

Following these steps solved my problem:

1. I have changed my python version to Python 3.9.1
2. Removed some folders from the API folder **python, venv, scripts** which seems to carry my older python location.
3. And just ran all the required libraries required to run my backend.