# wrong installing with 'pip install'

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, pip

I have problem with 'pip install'. And so with all libraries from pip. How i can to fix this?

```
PS C:\imapologize> pip install pyaudio
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using 
'"c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install 
pyaudio': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

Comment: [Your error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

Comment: Something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61419086/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-file-path1-file-path2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
python -m pip install "your library"
```

Comment: Ok, it's helped me. And right now I want move python file to .exe extension. With terminal and powershell I can't do it because I got the same error. What I should do?