# PIP and path issue on Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

So common error with several possible causes. 
Running

```
 pip install requests
```

results in the following error

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using
>   '"c:\users\foo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe" 
>   "C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pip.exe"

I've just installed Python 3.77 on Windows 10 to this location (after removing previous versions)

> c:\python37\

After searching here 
[Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python33\pip.exe""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86/25812942#25812942)

[Pip - Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using)

I tried using

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

which results in

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python37\lib\site-packages
>   (20.0.2)

And thinking it is a pathing issue I tried the following command but no difference

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\python37\lib\site-packages"

What should I try next?

Comment: from command prompt when you type c:\>  python --version what do you see ?

Comment: also check for c:\> pip3  --version

Comment: Thanks for feedback. So just entering python in the cmd line gives me 'python' is not recognized.... perhaps the setx command made things worse?
and pip3 --version 
returns the exact same error in my post above "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using...

Comment: to make it easier.. uninstall python 3.7 and reinstall.. when installing do custom and all users.. it will prompt for should add Python to Path.. do that.. it will make things easier for you.

Comment: yep my thoughts exactly. That should get me back to where I was but how to resolve the PIP issue? When I run pip in the cmd line it seems to be pointing to a non existing python install.

Comment: You can also try future installations with Package Managers like Chocolatey. Its like apt-get / YUM / Brew  for windows.

https://chocolatey.org/install

Comment: ok all good now. The ONLY real difference is that I chose install for All users. Also left the default install path for all users to Program Files. Thanks!! If you want o add your suggestions as answer will accept.

Comment: sure will do. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

to make it easier.. uninstall python 3.7 and reinstall.. when installing do custom and all users.. it will prompt for should add Python to Path..

You can also try future installations with Package Managers like Chocolatey. Its like apt-get / YUM / Brew for windows. chocolatey.org/install